# Are JPA repository delete operation synchronous?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

While using the JPA repository save operation, i observed the save operation is not synchronous.

Example code to explain the behaviour

```
   entity.setStatus(True);
   user_Entity = userRepository.save(entity);
   user_Entity.setStatus(False);
```

In this case, the status field is saved as False in the database. I read this is due to connection pooling and persistence JPA does not persist until the pool is exhausted or filled to some extent or after a time threshold. (my understanding)
The way around was to use save and FLush.

Now coming to the second scenario

Code example

```
  public void deleteByid(String Id) {
        if (!userRepository.existsById(Id))
            {
            log.info("No records found for Id {}",
                    Id);
            return;
            }
        log.info("Deleting user records for Id {}",
                Id);
        userRepository.deleteById(Id);
        if (!userRepository.existsById(Id)) {
            log.info("Successfully! deleted user records for Id {}",
                    Id);
        }else {
            log.info("Error! while deleting user records for Id {}",
                    Id);
            throw new DatabaseException("Exception ocurred while trying to delete ID");
        }
    }
```

IN this scenario the user repository.existsById(Id) gives False after deletion, that is it's synchronous.

Why the two different behaviour in two cases and is it guaranteed that the second code will always work in synchronous manner so the above code will not give any erroneous result??

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. Persistence operations are only performed after the transaction has committed. Which is after your `@Transactional` method finishes. With JPA all changes to a managed entity are persisted (that is the behavior for managed entities, state changes are automatically persisted on tx commit). Everything else is only visible for the current transaction.

Comment: So possible explational of above is the first code example was inside a `@Transactional` block while the other is not annotated with `@Transactional` so delete operation is performed as soon as it is called and control only moves to next step after deletion is complete??

Comment: No. The delete is visible to the current transaction, so doing a delete and then checking (within the same transaction if it is deleted) it will not find it. Checking it from a different transaction will still show it. The change hasn't been persisted to the database yet (a transaction is [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)) this is a perfect example of the isolation (as you and only you can see the change **until** it is committed (it is then Durable). The same applies to your first sample (false is only visible in the database **after** the transaction has been committed).

Comment: I see this explains it a lot thanks a lot!!, but I am still confused on one point, a particular transaction only knows about the changes done to the entity inside it. So why in the first case transaction not take into account the fact entity's status was changed only after saving. Is it due to object reference?

Comment: That is JPA, it will keep track of all the changes done to a managed entity and at the end of the transaction flush them to the database. (Assuming the default flush mode of auto).